# NodeJS POST to server with array as name attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, npm, query-string

First, I must clarify that I cannot use the express module, only default modules in node version 9.x.x
I have a form that has basic user info(name, birthday, email). This form can post several users information at once which the server will differentiate when parsed as an object. My problem is that each user may input an arbitrary amount of email, and I don't know how to post the email property without incorporating it into a 2d array in the query string. Below is an example form; as you can see, each user can input 2 emails.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:29184/" id="user">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fName"><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lName"><br>
    <label>Birthdate:</label>
    <input type="date" name="bday"><br>
    <label>Email1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email[0]"><br>
    <label>Email2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email[0]"><br>
    <h2>Another user</h2>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fName"><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lName"><br>
    <label>Birthdate:</label>
    <input type="date" name="bday"><br>
    <label>Email1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email[1]"><br>
    <label>Email2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email[1]"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

This is how i'm parsing it in my nodejs server:

```
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        var postObj = qs.parse(body);
        console.log(postObj);
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        fs.createReadStream("form.html").pipe(res);
        //res.end();
    });
```

postObj logs as:

```
{ fName: [ 'name1', 'name2' ],
  lName: [ 'last1', 'last2' ],
  bday: [ '111111-11-11', '2222-02-02' ],
  'email[0]': [ 'e1-1', 'e1-2' ],
  'email[1]': [ 'e2-1', 'e2-2' ] }
```

I can access postObj.fName[0] just fine, however I cannot access email[0][0] as an array. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I ended up adding another hidden input tag which stores the number of user emails, which is updated on a client side javascript when the user wishes to add another email. post all the emails in a single array, and have the server count how many emails each user has. Sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the properties as `postObj['email[0]'][0]`.

As a side point, `email[0]` and `email[1]` are unfortunate property names that will lead to confusion.